# Proof - convergent to compact and non-negative operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A_j$ be compact and non-negative operators for $\forall j$. 
If $|| A_j - A_0 || \rightarrow 0$, then $A_0$ is compact and $A_0$ is also nonnegative.

Could you give any hint or explanation how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as saying that:

1. For normed spaces $X,Y$, the space of compact operators is closed in the space of (bounded) linear operators.
2. Limits preserve inequalities.

For the first, it is useful to recall the definition of compact operators via $\varepsilon$-nets:
A collection of points $\mathcal{F}$ is called **an $\varepsilon$-net ** of $V$ if for every $x$ in $V$ there exists $y\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\|x-y\| <\varepsilon$.
Then, we say that $V$ is called pre-compact if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $\varepsilon$-net of $V$. This is all very topological and one can be (quite tediously) show that $V$ is pre-compact iff every sequence $(x_n) \subset V$ admits a cauchy sub-sequence (this will probably relate it to some other definitions of compact operators).

We can 
An operator $K\colon X \rightarrow Y$ is called compact, if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists finite $\varepsilon$-net of $K(B_X)$ where $B_X$ is the unit-ball of $X$.

Knowing that $A_n \rightarrow A_0$ can then be easily translated to showing that if every $A_n (B_x)$ is precompact - then so is $A_0$.

Another approach for the first part: If it is the definition with subsequences you use, that is, $K$ will be called compact if for every sequence $(x_n)$, $Kx_n$ has a cauchy subsequence: Then take a sequence $(x_n)$,you need it to find a subsequence $(x_{n_j})$ which is uniformally cauch, that is for every $m$ you have $A_m x_{n_j}$ is cauchy. Once you find that sequence, it is clear that $A_0 x_{n_j}$ should be cauchy too.

As for the latter (non-negativity): We first note that self-adjoint operators form a closed space.
Indeed, since $\| T \| = \|T^*\|$ we have $\|A_n -A_0 \| = \|A_n^* -A_0^*\|  = \|A_n -A_0^*\|$.
Then this is all a matter of taking the limit and repeating the mantra: "Limits preserve inequalities".

Comment: @Amin I added a hint for another approach.

Comment: @Amin this is a standard diagonal argument: Pick a sequence $(x_n)$. For $A_1$ there is a subsequence $x_{n_j}$ such that $(A_1 x_{n_j})$ is Cauchy. Denote this sub-sequence with $(x^{(1)}_n)$. Look at $A_2$ and the previous $(x^{(1)}_n)$ sequence.$A_2$ too is compact, and so there is a sub-sequence $(x^{(1)}_{n_j})$ such that $(A_2x^{(1)}_{n_j})$ is cauchy. Denote it $(x^{(2)}_n)$, and note it is a sub-sequence of  $(x^{(1)}_n)$, which in turn is a sub-sequence of $(x_n)$. Proceed in that manner, and then take the diagonal sequence: $(x^{(n)}_n)$. This one has the desired property.